# Loading many large PNG's with transparency on Retina display

Tags: ios, ipad, png, transparency

I'm creating up to five large UIViews; the UIViews are the full height of the screen and many times as wide. Each layer scrolls at a different speed, but they all contain a tiled collection of UIImageViews that are recycled.

I'm constantly finding which portion of each view is onscreen, and asynchronously loading the visible tiles into UIImages, then setting the image into the UIImageView back on the main thread. (using NSOperation for this.)

I got it to the point where it's super smooth on iPad 2. Then I got hold of an iPad 3 and plugged it in, and performance is terrible. I'm getting either slight hiccups or full-stop delays the whole time I'm scrolling.

I assume this is caused by the large amount of alpha blending being done on the retina display.

I tried CATiledLayer, and that fixed the scrolling motion hiccups, but the tile loading was suuuper slow. (I was calling setNeedsDisplay every time a new image was fully loaded, still slow.)

I've only found three changes that seem to help performance any:

1. My UIViews used to be cut into one row with many columns: each column was 128 points wide by the full height of the device. I cut the images into two rows: a top row of 128x512 points, and a bottom row of 128x256 points. (since I'm always landscape and iPad-only.)
2. Made sure tiles with only totally transparent pixels were nil'd, so they don't contribute to blending.
3. Reduced the number of layered UIViews. Also reduced the size of the scrolling views, in other words only loaded tiles into the top 2/3 of the screen.

Points 2 and 3 work because they reduce the overall number of pixels the app has to perform blending operations on.

But the problem is, they're compromises. I'd hate to have to start compromising like this when it's working so buttery-smooth on iPad2.

So my question is: is there anything I can do to improve the blending performance of images? I'd like to stay in outside OpenGL for this, if I go to OpenGL it would be a complete re-write, and the code falls together faster in UIKit, plus it plays nicer with a UIScrollView - since scrolling is kind of the gimmick with this, it'd be great to keep UIScrollView's native behavior.

So I'm hoping that there's something I don't know to get PNG transparency to magically blend faster, or that there's some other way to optimize the process on iPad 3. Thanks!

Comment: Everyone says the same thing about the iPad 3.  It's simply not capable of performing realtime full screen refreshes.  Draw in the smallest area you possibly can (via `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`).  My experience with CATiledLayer has not been that slow.  It is noticeable that the whole screen doesn't load at once, but that is the tradeoff for multicore async rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is I've got the equivalent of up to 5 fullscreen CATiledLayers, all with alpha transparency.

My latest hunch is that implementing my own scrolling logic will help, since I'll be able to control its maximum speed. I have some pretty good basic scrolling code, so I'll see what that does for me.